# IF Statement within Scrapy item declaration

Tags: python, css, if-statement, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to build a spider to monitor prices on a website. The website isn't consistent in how it displays it's prices. For it's standard price, it always uses the same CSS class, however when a product goes on promotion, it uses one of two CSS classes. The CSS selectors for both are below:

```
response.css('span.price-num:last-child::text').extract_first()
response.css('.product-highlight-label')
```

Below is how my items currently look within my spider:

```
    item = ScraperItem()

    item['model'] = extract_with_css('.product-id::text')
    item['link'] = extract_with_css('head meta[property="og:url"]::attr(content)')
    item['price'] = extract_with_css('span.list-price:last-child::text')
    item['promo_price'] = extract_with_css('span.price-num:last-child::text')


    yield item`
```

I would like to have something like:

IF `response.css('span.price-num:last-child::text')` is true

```
item['promo_price'] = extract_with_css('span.price-num:last-child::text')
```

ELSE `item['promo_price'] = extract_with_css('.product-highlight-label')`

Each way I've tried this I have failed.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. Here's my code:

```
    item = ScraperItem()

    item['model'] = extract_with_css('.product-id::text')
    item['link'] = extract_with_css('head meta[property="og:url"]::attr(content)')
    item['price'] = extract_with_css('span.list-price:last-child::text')

    if response.css('span.price-num:last-child::text'):
        item['promo_price'] = extract_with_css('span.price-num:last-child::text')
    else:
        item['promo_price'] = extract_with_css('.product-highlight-label::text')

    yield item
```